# RewriteCond : if image exist then show it, else generate it

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small php script which generates images (GD) for forum signatures. To call them there is an url like : http://www.example.net/img/imgtype_NN.png

Where :
- imgtype is the type of the signature I want
- NN is the ID of the image

When I call this url I want to test if the image already exists in the directory (i.e. if it already has been generated) and in this case I want to show it.

Otherwise I want my script to generate it and then show it.

Here is my actual .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} img/(.*)_(.*).png$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/signatures/img/%1_%2.png -f
RewriteRule img/(.*)_(.*).png$ /signatures/img/$1_$2.png [L]

RewriteRule img/(.*)_(.*).png /signatures/signatures.php?signature=$1&id_pop=$2 [L]
```

Images are stored in example.com/signatures/img/ and the php script is located in example.com/signatures/signatures.php

After hours of tries I don't have exactly what I need and I give up now, I need some help.

Thanks guys !

Comment: I had to move the rules before Wordpress' ones because he is already checking for existing files (and redirect to index.php). So now it works.

Thanks Justin !

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code is not the best so maybe your problem is due to some syntax error.
Anyway, you can try this version (put this code in your **root** htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/signatures/img/$1_$2\.png -f
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)_(.+)\.png$ /signatures/img/$1_$2.png [L]

RewriteRule ^img/(.+)_(.+)\.png$ /signatures/signatures.php?signature=$1&id_pop=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you've enabled *mod_rewrite* and allowed htaccess in Apache configuration

Comment: Actually my code worked... 50% of the time. I tried yours but I don't get why  the first RewriteCond is now gone. (%{REQUEST_URI}). With this code it doesn't work at all btw :)

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` is useless here since you're already matching it in `RewriteRule`. I'm really surprised your code is working randomly (50% of the time) that's totally weird. Do you have working and non-working url examples ? Also, is your htaccess in root folder ? Do you have other rules into it ? And do you have other htaccess files in other subfolders ?

Comment: Note that the requested url is /img/___.png but the files are in /signatures/img/ that's why I added a %REQUEST_URI. There are not url that work and others that don't but when I F5 the same url sometimes it works sometimes not.

Comment: Yes, that's what my rules are doing (just like yours, actually). Looks more like a cache problem to me. Are you, by any chance, using Nginx ? Also, you didn't answer my questions: is your htaccess in root folder ? Is *mod_rewrite* well enabled and htaccess allowed (apache config) ? And most of all, do you have other rules in your htaccess ? Or other htaccess in subfolders ?

Comment: Sorry. The .htaccess is in root folder (it's a Wordpress) and rewrite mod activated and htaccess allowed (other rules are working well). There is no other htacces in subfolders. I'm using Apache (with Varnish)

Comment: Well i guess what's the problem here. Could you update your post with your **entire** (WP) htaccess (including your personal rules) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78240/discussion-between-cyc-and-justin-iurman).